# Can improved window insulation prevent condensation on the interior of a window

Tags: insulation, windows, condensation

We have a whole house humidifier which is great but one of our windows condenses much more than the others and doesn't dry out because it doesn't get much sun during the day like our other windows.  I talked to a window contractor about getting a new, well-insulated window installed.  I thought if the window is well-insulated, then the interior of the window will be warmer and so less condensation will form.  The contractor said that this wouldn't help, and that the primary problem is the air getting trapped between the blinds and the windows, and that we should instead try to leave the blinds open and of course turn down our humidifier a bit.

## My question:

Will better window insulation (either by getting glass with a high [R-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(insulation)), or by some sort of [window insulation kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002NCJI)) reduce condensation on our window interior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a single pane window growing to a double or triple pane window will help. To prove thus to yourself put a flash of ice water in the room and a glass of warm water, some may say Duh but a single pane window is the same as the ice water double or triple pane is similar to warm water. A dehumidifier in that room would also reduce the moisture, or things like a vent fan in the bathroom if it doesent have one it will really help. Not sure why the contractor would not think better windows would help unless you already have double pane.

Comment: The window is already double pane, but a pretty thin double pane.  I talked to another contractor who seems to agree that better insulation should reduce condensation.  I was just so confused after talking the to first contractor that I asked a question on here just to make sure I wasn't crazy.